# how do I install QGIS for Android?

Tags: qgis, android

I am new to Android (just brought a Nexus 7) and I am trying to get QGIS onto it but I can not find any installation instructions.  I have found http://android.qgis.org/download/qgis-installer.apk and when I click on the link I get the warning that "such files may damage my computer", I click "continue" and there is a brief popup "downloading..." and that is it.  Nothing else happens.

I have only ever installed apps from the "play store" in the past.

I am still coming to grips with computers that don't have a command line shell ;)

Russell

Comment: Not GIS specific: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9718104/how-to-install-apk-from-pc however note that this is installing the installer, not QGIS. Having installed the installer, invoke the installer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check the "Downloads" app, the APK should be listed there.  Just tap on it in the "Downloads" app to install.  You may get prompted again to allow installation of apps not from Google Play.